# SDL UpdateWindowSurface() returns -1 if called from a class (in separate file)

Tags: c++, class, window, header-files, sdl-2

Today I started a C++/SDL2 Snake clone, and I've been looking for ways to make my code neater, -particularly with classes. I tried to put all the SDL code used for the window/display in a class. When I run the code, **the window closes instantly**. From the error tests I set up in display.cpp, it also tells me through the console that **SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() (in display.update()) is always returning -1. Why does this happen when I rearrange my code like this?**

With this code I load an image in main() and display it through my class' function applySurface(). The idea is to have classes/objects for the game's grid/board, the snake, etc., -each calling applySurface() for their own images. Feel free to tell me if this is a bad idea altogether.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include "display.h"

SDL_Event event;
SDL_Surface* image = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    Display display;
    display.loadImage("image.bmp");

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1)
        return false;

    bool quit = false;

    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = true;
        }

        display.applySurface(0, 0, image, display.windowSurface);
        display.update();
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

**display.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Display
{
public:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Surface* windowSurface;

    Display();
    SDL_Surface *loadImage(std::string fileName);
    void applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect *clip = nullptr);
    void update();
    ~Display();
private:
    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 612;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 632;
    const int SCREEN_BPP = 2;
};
```

**display.cpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include "display.h"

Display::Display()
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Snake", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL)
        std::cout << "Error: SDL_CreateWindow failed." << std::endl;

    windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
}

SDL_Surface* Display::loadImage(std::string fileName)
{
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(fileName.c_str());

    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        optimizedImage = SDL_ConvertSurface(loadedImage, windowSurface->format, 0);

        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);

        if (optimizedImage != NULL)
            SDL_SetColorKey(optimizedImage, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(optimizedImage->format, 255, 255, 255));
    }

    return optimizedImage;
}


void Display::applySurface(int x, int y, SDL_Surface *source, SDL_Surface *destination, SDL_Rect *clip)
{
    SDL_Rect offset;

    offset.x = x;
    offset.y = y;

    SDL_BlitSurface(source, clip, destination, &offset);
}

void Display::update()
{
    if (SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window) == -1)
        std::cout << "Error: SDL_UpdateWindowSurface() failed." << std::endl;
}

Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(windowSurface);
    windowSurface = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `SDL_Init` must be called before any other `SDL_` functions, but both `Display::Display()` and `Display::loadImage(std::string)` are called before you call `SDL_Init` in your `main` function. You should probably move `SDL_Init` to the top of `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid use of classes to structure your code. `SDL_Init` needs to come before any other SDL functions, which means you're best off moving `SDL_Init` to the top of main or adding it to the display constructor. If you add it to the beginning of the display constructor this means that you can only have one display class object running at a time, which would likely be fine in this case.

Comment: The issue now though, is that the image will not appear on the screen. I just get the black background of the window. I can't see any reason for this, -the images seem to be loading/optimizing fine.

Comment: Have you tried defining offset.h and offeset.w? Moving the image coordinates to a non-origin point may help also.